# Player not jumping off platform

Tags: javascript, game-development

I made a simple player and platform for it to stand on, but the player won't jump when it is standing on the platform. Here is my code:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var isJumping = false
canvas.width = 1024;
canvas.height = 576;
const gravity = 0.2
class Player {
    constructor(x, y, width, height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.velocityY = 0;
        this.velocityX = 0
    }
    draw() {
        c.fillStyle = 'red';
        c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
    update() {
        this.y += this.velocityY
        if(this.y + this.height + this.velocityY<= canvas.height){
            this.velocityY += gravity
            this.y += this.velocityY
        }else{
            this.velocityY = 0 
            isJumping = false
        }
        this.x += this.velocityX
        this.draw();
    }
}
class Platform{
    constructor(x,y,width,height){
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.width = width
        this.height = height
    }
    draw(player){
        c.fillStyle = 'green'
        c.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height)

        if(player.y <= this.y && player.y+player.height>=this.y&& player.x+player.width>=this.x && player.x<=this.x+this.width){
            player.velocityY = 0
            player.y = this.y-player.height
            isJumping = false
        }
    }
}
const player = new Player(0, 0, 50, 100);
const platform = new Platform(0,300,100,50)
function update() {
    c.fillStyle = 'black'
    c.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height) // Clear the canvas on each frame
    platform.draw(player)
    player.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(update); // Request the next frame
}

update(); // Start the animation loop

addEventListener('keydown', (event)=>{
    if(event.code==="KeyD"){
        player.velocityX=3
    }
    if(event.code==="KeyA"){
        player.velocityX=-3
    }
    if(event.code==="Space"&& isJumping == false){
        player.velocityY = -8
        isJumping = true
    }
})

addEventListener('keyup', (event)=>{
    if(event.code==="KeyD"){
        player.velocityX=0
    }
    if(event.code==="KeyA"){
        player.velocityX=0
    }
})
```

I expected the player to be able to jump off the platform, but it won't. I've tried everything I can, but it still won't work. I'm assuming it has something to do with the velocity of the player, can someone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

On your `platform` class, try creating a condition that checks if the bottom of the player is at or below the top of the platform and if the player's next position will be above the platform

```
if (player.y + player.height >= this.y && player.y + player.height + player.velocityY <= this.y && player.x + player.width >= this.x && player.x <= this.x + this.width) {
player.velocityY = 0;
player.y = this.y - player.height;
isJumping = false;}
```